# Запрет ввода в TextField строк и символов

Tags: java, javafx

На сцене есть несколько `TextField`, как сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить только целые числа или числа типа 0.5 и т.д.?

Нашел такую реализацию, но как сделать, чтобы точку тоже можно было ставить?

```
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> integerFilter = change -> {
    String newText = change.getControlNewText();
    if (newText.matches("-?([1-9][0-9]*)?")) {
        return change;
    }
    return null;
};

gerp1n.setTextFormatter(
        new TextFormatter<Integer>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 0, integerFilter));
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `TextFormatter`

Comment: В вопрос добавил реализацию, которую нашел, но непонятно как сделать, возможность указать точку.

Comment: Вот пример для `Double` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981297/4444092

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: Реализация из `SceneBuilder`а: https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/blob/master/kit/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/util/control/paintpicker/DoubleTextField.java